# Difference between object and returning object from IIFE

Tags: javascript

Using `this` keyword inside functions of an object works, but refering to other functions without `this` doesn't. When I put out those functions before the object, both ways work. Why is that so?

```
var Obj = {
  func1: function () {
    console.log(this.func2()); // works
    console.log(func2()); // doesn't work
  },
  func2: function () {
    return 5;
  }
};
Obj.func1();
```

But doing the same in IIFE:

```
var Obj = (function () {
  function func1() {
    console.log(this.func2()); // works
    console.log(func2()); // works
  }
  function func2() {
    return 5;
  }
  return {
    func1: func1,
    func2: func2
  };
})();
Obj.func1();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the IIFE, in the first example you have an object literal, in the second regular functions.

Of course, object literals would need the name of the object (or `this` if the this-value ***is*** the object, like inside an object literal) followed by the property to access it, while named functions can be accessed anywhere in that scope by just using the name.

```
var obj = {
    prop : function() {...}
}

prop(); // fail ... undefined
obj.prop(); // works

// then _______________________________________________________________

function prop() {...}

prop(); // works fine
```

This is really what you're doing, you've just wrapped it up in different objects and immediately invoked function expressions, so it looks somewhat the same, but it's not.

Answer (score -1):

**There is no difference.**

In both cases, you're working with an `object`. So, you need to use `this` or the object `name` to call the function defined under an object.

Comment: well, this is just not correct. See accepted answer